# Aggregate two columns and rows into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I have the following table structure

```
start|end
09:00|11:00
13:00|14:00
```

I know

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(start), ARRAY_AGG(end)
```

Will result in

```
start|end
[09:00,13:00]|[11:00,14:00]
```

But how can i get the following result?
result

```
[09:00,11:00,13:00,14:00]
```

BTW, I'm using Postgres

Comment: What is  the datatype of `start` and `end` ?

Comment: Timestamp without time zone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do array concatenation (if order is not important):

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(start) || ARRAY_AGG(end) FROM TABLE1
```

If order is important you could use [Gordon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) approach **but**:

- add aggregate order `array_agg(d order by d ASC)`
- use `unnest` instead of `union all`, because Gordon's solution (`union all`) performs two sequence scan. If table is big it could be better for performance to use:

  ```
  SELECT array_agg(d ORDER BY d ASC) FROM(
      SELECT unnest(ARRAY[start] || ARRAY[end]) as d from table1
  ) sub
  ```

which performs only one sequence scan on table (and will be faster).

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, but orders is important

Comment: @GuilhermeMiranda I've edited my answear to add order in consideration

Answer (score 1):

One method is to unpivot them and then aggregate:

```
select array_agg(d)
from (select start as d from t
      union all
      select end as d from t
     ) t;
```

A similar method uses a `cross join`:

```
select array_agg(case when n.n = 1 then t.start else t.end end)
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

Comment: With the OP's data, won't this give `[09:00,13:00,11:00,14:00]`? I'm unclear from the OP if the ordering matters, but if it does, it seems as though your answer is missing a part.

Comment: @GordonLinoff probably need to add agragate order `array_agg(d order by d)` to get exact result posted in question

Comment: @GordonLinoff In addition if he needs to do it on whole table, using `union all` on big table could be slower than `unnest` as I explain [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33257542/5404196)

Comment: @Gabriel'sMessanger . . . The `cross join` should not be doing two sequential scans.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes thats true. But you show two methods. I was talking about first of them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `start` and `end` are *character* type

```
select ARRAY_AGG(col) 
from(select string_agg(strt::text||','||en::text,',') col 
     from b
)t
```